# Can we establish connection with Cognos 10.2.1 with Hive 0.11 or 0.12?

Tags: jdbc, hive, hadoop2, cognos-10

I am new to Cognos and I am trying have a connection between Cognos 10.2.1 and Hive 0.11 through JDBC Connectivity. I installed Cognos 10.2.1 on Windows machine and Hadoop on Ubuntu. Can I establish connection between them, it would be helpful for me if you provide the different Jar file names that I need to copy from the Hive to Cognos server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is the recommendation from Hive to use higher versions of hive (higher than hive 1.0.0)  for JDBC with Hiverserver2 support.

Reference: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient

You need following jars for JDBC connectivity

```
 hive-jdbc-<version no>.jar                    
 hive-jdbc-<version no>-standalone.jar
```

Comment: Hello Addy, thanks for giving this answer to me I tried with these two drivers, the Cognos server is unable to start when I copied these two files to the Cognos server. Are these files are uselful as I am using Hive 0.11 but these are for Hive 2.0

Comment: I can't find Hive stand alone jar file for the version 0.11. Can you please guide me on this

Comment: Hello Addy, can't I connect the Cognos using Hive 0.11 or something lesser than the version 0.14. I have searching through the net, for hive-jdbc-<version no>-standalone.jar will available after 0.14 version.But one of the tutorial that I have followed said that the Cognos can only able to connect Hive versions 0.8 to 0.12.